# Getting the overall average

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get the overall average of the grades. I was able to get the average of each individual grade. Now just to get the total I'm not sure how to get it.

My output is:

```
Quizzes:66.0
Labs:88.0
Lab_atendance: 81.0
Midterms:91.0
```

---

```
public static double average(int[] scoreArray, int numScores,
                             int maxGrade, String name) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        sum += scoreArray[i];
    }
    double average = Math.round((sum / numScores)*100/maxGrade);

    System.out.println( name + ":" + average+" %");

    return average;
}
```

Comment: Your average calculation seems suspect, generally that should have the form `double average = sum / scoreArray.length;`

Comment: @Elliott basically he is calculating percentage of his average!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in not `average` exactly! but still..

Do the same procedure for Quizzes, Labs, Lab_attendance and Midterms! *Isn't it obvious?*

Here your numScores will be 4!

So from your given input

`Avg = ((66.0 + 88.0 + 81.0 + 91.0) / 4) * 100 / maxGrade)`

Comment: He said those numbers were the output.

Comment: OP specifies that input is an `int []`

Comment: If he want's overall average then he should take average of all individual grades! isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your average calculation (and method signature) seem incorrect (averages are not calculated by dividing a "max"), I would use something like

```
// Note the new method signature - name then a variable number of scores.
public static double average(String name, int... scores) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int score : scores) { // <-- for each loop.
    sum += score;
  }
  final double average = (scores != null) ? sum / scores.length : 0;

  System.out.println(name + ":"
      + Math.round(average * 100) + " %"); //<-- Display as a percentage
  return average;
}
```